# Best way to save results for searching

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function:

```
function dist($addr, $addr2){
    $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins='.urlencode($addr).'&destinations='.urlencode($addr2).'&key=<key>';
    $json = curl_download($url);
    //$json = preg_replace('/^\xEF\xBB\xBF/', '', $json);
    $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    return $array['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
}
```

Using google api its calculating the distance between two locations. This script generally takes between 0.3-0.6 seconds per call of the function. So what i want to do is 'cache' the results so it doesnt need to call the url everytime? Would be putting the results and the search criteria in a DB the best way? Then check if they are in the DB before using the function

How would i go about quickening the search and making a page load as fast as possible?

Comment: You are asking for a very common programming technique called "memoization". Google that term and you will find a multitude of ways to implement it. You should find a way that you like.

Comment: @kainaw thank you, i'll have a loot at that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this realistic? I don't know what your application is for, but there is a near infinite list of distances if the user can input any address. An average of half a second waiting time for such heavy calculations is incredibly quick. Digging through millions of records in a database takes more time than that API call.

If however, this method is often called with the same parameters (thus addresses), setting up a little database or even JSON file with that outcome might not be a bad idea. JSON is a lot faster than MySQL, so if you really have to cache results, I'd use that.

Comment: Is JSON that much faster? Because i am comparing a user defined location against 50+ preset locations (which is increasing) what performance benefits can i see from JSON?

Comment: In this case it probably is. Arrays can be loaded a lot faster than a MySQL table. Keep in mind that we're talking about real small arrays like the one Farkie wrote. For bigger datasets that need normalizing, always use a DBMS.

Comment: Regarding the ToS by Google, use a DBMS like MySQL and set all records to be removed after 30 days of creation.

Answer (score 0):

We tend to use a `name/key value` store to do something like that.

You have a table which just stores the request parameters, and the return response.

```
Key1 | Key2 | Value | 
POSTCODE1 | POSTCODE2 | {response from google} |
```

Now just before you do the search to google, you check this table first, and if it exists, just use the response. If it doesn't exist, then do your lookup, and store it in the database.

I should point out that I believe Google say in their ToS that you shouldn't cache this data.

Comment: Yes, you can cache it. But for max of 30 days and its stored securely

Comment: Ah cool :) good to know! Can you mark one of the answers as the correct one? :)

Answer (score 0):

you can save the result in Redis (http://redis.io/) this is a Database in memory Ram, is awesome for velocity. :D